# Missing GUI application for 7-Zip?

Tags: compression, file-roller, 7zip

I installed [7-Zip from Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/p7zip-full/), but where is the GUI application?

---

Original question asked by a user:

> ich habe 7Zip aus dem Softwarecentrum installiert, finde aber kein
>   Symbol zum öffnen des Programmes. Kann hier jemand helfen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package `p7zip` you installed from [Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center) contains a port of the command line utility included in the 7-Zip installer for Windows. It does not include any applications with a graphical user interface (GUI) like `7ZipFM.exe`. Instead, it extends the functionality of the archive and extract tool (`file-roller`, [page in Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/file-roller/)) included in the default installation.

[image: Picture showing compress dialog with 7z set as output format. The language is German; please replace.]

## LZMA, LZMA2, XZ and RAR support

`p7zip` may only include support for the [LZMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm) compression algorithm, not for LZMA2. For that you should install the `xz-utils` [package from Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xz-utils/) and set the output format to `.xz` or better `.tar.xz` or `.txz` to preserve file attributes.

For support of the `.rar` format you should install the `unrar-free` [package from Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unrar-free/) and run the program from terminal, as that seems to provide the best support for this particular format.

## Change the default compression level

See: [Set 7z compression level using GUI in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/562491/40581)

---

Please understand that questions and answers can only be asked and answered in English, but you may find helpful German support over at [ubuntuusers.de](http://ubuntuusers.de/).

Answer (score 4):

You can install PeaZip if you want powerfull GUI on the backbone of 7zip.

Please type these commands on terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi

wget -c launchpadlibrarian.net/70575443/libgmp3c2_4.3.2%2Bdfsg-2ubuntu1_i386.deb

wget http://optimate.dl.sourceforge.net/project/peazip/5.4.1/peazip_5.4.1.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb

sudo gdebi libgmp3c2_4.3.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1_i386.deb

sudo gdebi peazip_5.4.1.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb
```

Comment: p7zip does not support 7zip files decompression when password encrypted. PeaZip does.

Comment: this line fails: "wget http://optimate.dl.sourceforge.net/project/peazip/5.4.1/peazip_5.4.1.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb"

Answer (score 1):

To install Peazip on Ubuntu:

1. [Download the needed file from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/peazip/files/)

   - `peazip_x.x.x.LINUX.GTK2-2_i386.deb` (32-bits)
   - `peazip_x.x.x.LINUX.GTK2-2_all.deb`  (64-bits)
2. For 64-bit machine (if 32 bits machine go to step 3)

> sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0:i386 libc6:i386 libcairo2:i386
>   libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386
>   libpango1.0-0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i38

3. Install the downloaded package from step 1

That is it, you are done !

Step 2 is needed because the 64-bit package requires ia-32 libs, which is no available in Ubuntu since Ubuntu 13.10. The “fix” is to simply install the 32bit dependency libraries on 64bit Ubuntu, and that’s how multiarch works.

So first open terminal from Unity Dash, App Launcher, or via Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut key. When it opens, paste below command and run to install dependencies:

Comment: tried on Ubuntu 16.04, peazip throws "symbol lookup error: peazip: undefined symbol: QApplication_hook_hook_commitDataRequest". Seems to be an old problem: https://sourceforge.net/p/peazip/tickets/320/