How do I use 7zip GUI on UBuntu 24.04
I installed Ubuntu 24.04. I installed 7ZIP-Desktop. Tried various install methods including APT and SNAP.
I cannot figure out how to invoke p7zip-desktop using Nautilus under Ubuntu or Ubuntu-Flashback.

Hello StanBarr. i found a similar question that may have the answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/369851/missing-gui-application-for-7-zip

Does this answer your question? Missing GUI application for 7-Zip?

It is a good thought, but I made sure the 7-zip GUI was installed. I tried various ways of installing 7-zip prior to posting my question.

AFAIK, Ubuntu 24.04 no longer supports the 7-zip GUI.
The command line works fine. I use 7-zip to compress and to encrypt/decrypt. It is very convenient as the operation is the same on Linux and Windows.
So we must rely on a 3rd party solution until/if the GUI is fixed.
Here is an interim solution using a Nautilus (Aka File) script:
#!/bin/bash
#1Decrypt
gnome-terminal -e "$HOME/bin/Decrypt ${1}"

Here is Decrypt:
#!/bin/bash
#Decrypt
echo -n "Enter the password: "
read -s pw
filename="$@"
f="${filename%%.*}"
7z x $1 -p"${pw}" -o"${f}"
sleep 5
exit 0

This pair of scripts will take an encrypted 7-zip archive of say, name.7z, and decrypt it to folder name. You right-click on name.7z and choose Scripts and under Scripts choose 1Decrypt. The script asks for the password. The password is not displayed. name.7z is then decrypted to folder name.
I chose 1Decrypt as the Nautilus (File) script name so that it sorts near the top of my scripts.
Scripts are saved in:
$HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts

I usually include a script named open-nautilus-script that opens the folder:
#!/bin/sh
#open Nautilus script directory
nautilus ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts

Place 1Decrypt in $HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts.
Place Decrypt in $HOME/bin.
Place open-nautilus-script in $HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts.

Does not work out of the box, after installing the command line tools, install file-roller and restart. This also works with encrypted .7z files.
sudo apt install -yq 7zip p7zip-full file-roller

In the file-browser, select Open With... on a .7z file and select File-roller.
